# Spring MVC: add response header for deprecated endpoints dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, openapi

Suppose that I have some endpoint that's marked as deprecated:

```java
@RestController
class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/api/hello")
    @Deprecated(forRemoval = true)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, world";
    }
}
```

I also use [SpringDoc](https://springdoc.org/) to generate OpenAPI specification. Therefore, this endpoint shall be marked as deprecated in the spec too (due to `@Deprecated` annotation presence).

I want to add an MVC filter that'll add custom response header `X-Deprecated`, if the endpoint is deprecated. So, the client will know that it's using some deprecated endpoint.

Do you have any ideas how to achieve it? I understand that `@Deprecated` annotation has `RUNTIME` retention policy and I can parse it with Reflection API. However, I'm not sure how to make a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object handler` in interceptor

```
public class LoggerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, @Nullable ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;

            if (method.getMethod().getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) != null) {
                response.addHeader("X-Deprecated", "true");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then register it to `WebMvcConfigurer`

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
                registry.addInterceptor(new LoggerInterceptor());
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: This answer adds an "X-Deprecated" header. Instead it should be adding a "Deprecation" header and perhaps related headers such as 'Sunset'. See: https://imhoratiu.wordpress.com/2021/01/20/respectful-rest-apis-sunset-and-deprecation-http-headers/#:~:text=2-,Deprecation%3A%20true,-Link%3A%20http%3A//reviews

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Spring AOP* to create an `@After` Pointcut over the `@Deprecated` annotation. In the method execution then you can add the header you want

If you need additional information on *AOP* check this: [*Implementing a Custom Spring AOP Annotation*](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-annotation)